# SQL - Column per week (X weeks from declared start date)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to run a select statement that returns a number of invoices with their values showing in a column that's appropriate to the week that the invoice appeared in.  Example:

```
id value  invoiced
1  150    2014-01-06
2  220    2014-01-13
3  190    2014-01-13
4  880    2014-01-27
5  325    2014-02-03
```

I would need this data to display in a format similar to below:

```
ID  W/E 2014-01-05  W/E 2014-01-12  W/E 2014-01-19  W/E 2014-01-26  W/E 2014-02-02  W/E 2014-02-09  W/E 2014-02-16
1   0               150             0               0               0               0               0
2   0               0               220             0               0               0               0
3   0               0               190             0               0               0               0
4   0               0               0               0               880             0               0
5   0               0               0               0               0               325             0
```

With the first date being taken from a variable and the remaining weeks being calculated from that point on (for X weeks).  My initial thought is to use a temporary table to hold rows for each of the date ranges and then join that table to perform a pivot... but to be honest this is all pretty new to me so I have absolutely no idea of the syntax.

There is no requirement for any grouping (no sums to deal with), I just need to make sure that the appropriate values end up in the appropriate columns.

p.s.  I know I could do this with loops on the presentation layer, but in this particular case, there isn't one as such.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (Id INT,Value INT,invoiced Date )
insert into  @t (Id,Value,invoiced)values (1,150,'2014-01-06')
insert into  @t (Id,Value,invoiced)values (2,220,'2014-01-13')
insert into  @t (Id,Value,invoiced)values (3,190,'2014-01-15')
insert into  @t (Id,Value,invoiced)values (4,880,'2014-01-27')
insert into  @t (Id,Value,invoiced)values (5,325,'2014-01-29')
Select id,
    [w/e2014-01-06],
    [w/e2014-01-13],
    [w/e2014-01-15],
    [w/e2014-01-27],
    [w/e2014-01-29]
         from
(Select distinct t.ID,t.Value,
    'w/e' + CAST(t.invoiced AS VARCHAR)AS Dateno 
        from @t t)t
PIVOT (MAX(value)FOR Dateno IN([w/e2014-01-06],[w/e2014-01-13],[w/e2014-01-15],[w/e2014-01-27],[w/e2014-01-29]))p
```